# Xamarin.Forms Update one element in ListView

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

i want to update listview elements using mvvm in Xamarin.Forms. I followed some tutorials on web and now i can add new item and remove any item to my listview.
However i can not update any specific item

This is my ViewModel Class:

```
public class CarsViewModels : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Car> items;

    public ObservableCollection<Car> Items
    {
        get { return items; }

        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public CarsViewModels()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Car>() 
        {
            new Car()
            {
                CarID = 1,
                Make = "Tesla Model S"
            },
              new Car()
            {
                CarID = 2,
                Make = "Audi R8"
            },
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And this is add,remove and change methods from my xaml.cs file

```
private void AddNewItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add(new Car{CarID = 3, Make = "new car"});
    }

    private void RemoveItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedITem = (Button)sender;
        var clickedCar = (Car) clickedITem.BindingContext;

        items.Remove(clickedCar);
    }

    private void ChangeThisItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        var clickedCar = (Car)clickedITem.BindingContext;

        var changedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CarID == clickedCar.CarID);

        if (changedItem != null)
        {
            changedItem.Make = "text has changed";
        }
    }
```

Add and remove methods works but i can not update make property of car model. Any help ?

Comment: does your Car class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Thank you Jason you are right. I have implement it and added this piece of code to my class:                                                                                      public string Make
  {
   get { return _Make; }
   set
   {
    _Make = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Make");
   }
  }


  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));